# Upload video fail to youtube from asp.net website by data api

Tags: asp.net, youtube

I am trying to upload video in my ASP.net website to YouTube using the data API but I am getting this error: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

I am using the below code:

YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("VideoPortal", "Developer_Key", "username", "password");
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

Video newVideo = new Video();

```
        newVideo.Title = "testvideo";//txttitle.Text.Trim();
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = "testvideo";//txtkeyword.Text.Trim();
        newVideo.Description = "testvideodesc";//txtdesc.Text.Trim();
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
          YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);
        // alternatively, you could just specify a descriptive string
        // newVideo.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Mountain View, CA");
        string path = Server.MapPath("video/Screen-Recording.mov");
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(path,
          "video/quicktime");
        settings.Timeout = 100000000;
        Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Can anybody please suggest to me how I can make this code work and resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

what the HTTP response body's content is when you get back your HTTP 403 response? There should be an error message in the response body that provides an explanation of what went wrong